# Google Analytics Tag - Non Standard Implementation

Tags: shopify, google-tag-manager

Google tag assistant shows non standard implementation for my google analytics tag. I have added the tag - (Google Analytics: Universal Analytics) in Google Tag Manager - with my correct Analytics tracking ID. I have placed my GTM installation tags properly and they are not showing any error on Google Tag Assistant.

I am using shopify and I have added my analytics ID in the store preferences as well (screenshot attached).

I want to know what's wrong with Analytics Tag, please refer to the screenshots and suggest any wayout. Thanks!

P.S I can post pictures here until I have 10 reputations points. Still Please help me by any means.

Comment: Is the snippet taken from GTM and in page is the same also after deploy or is it changed to by the CMS being deployed? Is the GTM snippet position in page the same requested by Google?